# Pass Properties as JSON in SoapUI

Tags: json, rest, soapui

I have a series of creation steps as an example of the use case for the program I'm working on. For example, a user must first create a CASE and send the response _id (database key), as the case_id when creating an IDENTITY.

POST CASE request:

```
{ "display_name" : "Sample Case"}
```

Response:

```
[{
   "synthetic": false,
   "last_updated": "2014-08-25 16:50:07.956611",
   "encrypted": false,
   "date_created": "2014-08-25 16:50:07.956602",
   "_id": "53fb693fc41be928380d5fe0",
   "display_name": "Sample Case"
}]
```

Response In XML:

```
<Response>
   <e>
      <_id>53fb693fc41be928380d5fe0</_id>
      <date_created>2014-08-25 16:50:07.956602</date_created>
      <display_name>Sample Case</display_name>
      <encrypted>false</encrypted>
      <last_updated>2014-08-25 16:50:07.956611</last_updated>
      <synthetic>false</synthetic>
   </e>
</Response>
```

POST IDENTITY Request:

```
{
    "display_name" : "John Doe",
    "case_id" : "53fb693fc41be928380d5fe0",
    "type" : "person",
}
```

The issue I'm having is that while I can capture the _id value from a case response, and fill that into a set of properties, I can't figure out how to turn that properties object into a JSON request (which the program I'm working with requires for REST requests).

Is there a way to dynamically create JSON data for a REST request using the Test Suite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to just insert something from a previous Response, you can use SoapUI property expansion:

```
${previous_step_name#ResponseAsXml#//*:_id}
```

So your example would look something like:

```
{
    "display_name" : "John Doe",
    "case_id" : "${previous_step_name#ResponseAsXml#//*:_id}",
    "type" : "person",
}
```

If you need something more fancy to "dynamically create JSON data", you would need to explain what it is that you want. Here is something to possibly get you started: http://siking.wordpress.com/2013/07/05/dynamically-create-elements-in-a-soapui-request-json-version/

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding where that string would go. Is it in the application/json box when creating the request for my Create_Identity TestStep, or is it used during the PropertyTransfer step?

Comment: Ok, now it seems to work. For some reason it didn't work the first time I tried it. I think because I still had an intermediary step (a script that passed the vars but was less intuitive) and it didn't like that, even though I used the right names.

Answer (score 0):

JSONBuilder is an option like @SiKing says.

A very simple solution for this is adding to differents templates to your project with the format of every Request.

CaseTemplate.json ->

```
{ "display_name" : "${display_name}"}
```

IdentityTemplate.json ->

```
{
"display_name" : "Sample Case",
"case_id" : "${case_id}",
"type" : "${display_name}"
}
```

Then before every request test step, in a property transfer you can set the **Request Property** of a request test step with the content of one of this payloads.

```
Source: Name_of_your_project -> Property:IdentityTemplate
Target: Request_test_step_name -> Property: Request
```

And then set all the properties of your new template, in another property transfer.

*Make sure you have correctly defined this properties in the interface of the rest request.*

Comment: Are templates a special object is SoapUI? I don't see how to create them so as to get what you are showing in the "property transfer" step. Is there a way to instead transfer directly to the create_identity step if I have the request built in that step, in the application/json section, with the variables as "${case_id}"?

Comment: I add templates as global properties of my project in soapUI. So then you can use them so i can reuse in my project any time i need.